# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Sorry to bother with this kind of question but i am kinda sick of this...
Got a problem with rather simple thing...

This piece of code:

```
$mysql_key = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace($mysql_remove, '', $key));

$mysql_value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

$insert = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE archi_form SET ".$mysql_key." = ".$mysql_value." WHERE random_string = '".$randstring."'");
```

is throwing me this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= WHERE random_string='pq9HzavnyQdC1ZrCODsV1HDc0xcV6jXdPT20TNRjTM0pjzgd9jJO3EgXT' at line 1 1064

Could you help please before i will loose me mind? :)

Comment: its because you are mixing tow different api ..use mysqli_real_escape_string instead

Comment: Please start using `mysqli_*` or `pdo` not the depracted `mysql_*`

Comment: Surely it's better to prepare statements. That's kind of the point of the mysqli API

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`

You can't do that, because it won't work. You must use only the `mysqli_*` functions.

Rephrased from the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) pages:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE archi_form SET $column = ? WHERE random_string = ?")) {

  /* bind parameters for markers */
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value, $randstring);

  /* execute query */
  $stmt->execute();

  /* bind result variables */
  $stmt->bind_result($result);

  /* fetch value */
  $stmt->fetch();

  //do something

  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Note that I didn't use mysqli_real_escape_string. Read the PHP doc to discover why.

Special note for `$column`. As far as I know, you can't bind column or table names. Therefore, you need a form of whitelisting:

```
$valid_columns = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
if (in_array($mysql_key, $valid_columns)){
    $column = $mysql_key
} else {
    echo "something fishy is going on"; die;
}
```

Comment: well, PDO documentation is very good. I don't use mysqli to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'= WHERE**

You are getting this error means there is nothing in **$mysql_value**, because error showing `= **???** WHERE` , Check this value ,and also correct your query as below

```
"UPDATE archi_form SET ".$mysql_key." = '".$mysql_value."' WHERE random_string = '".$randstring."'"
```